# How can I delete SharePoint site groups using Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, flow, power-automate

I am trying to use Power Automate to delete a bunch of SharePoint site groups but it does not seem to be working. My flow is successful but the group(s) are not removed. Google results seem to be more related to removing users from groups, not removing the groups themselves.

Can anyone explain what I've done wrong with my flow action?

My knowledge of REST is very limited at this stage.

**My Site group:**

[image: Text]

**My Flow action:**

[image: Text]

**The Flow output:**

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your flow like below. This works for me:

[image]

**OR** simply like:

[image]

**Group Settings**:

[image]

**Notable Points**:

1. I have used endpoint like: `/_api/web/sitegroups/removebyid('<group-id>')`. Group ID is enclosed by single quote (`'`).
2. In my case I am the owner for both group and flow.
3. Or you can set Who can view the membership of the group in Group settings to Everyone.

**Reference**: [Delete A SharePoint Group Using Microsoft Flow/Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/02/delete-a-sharepoint-group-using-microsoft-flow-power-automate/)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. The issue was the Group owner. It was not set to the account I was expecting. As soon as I changed it, the flow worked great. I had checked permissions everywhere but on the groups themselves!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the flow output in this case, all you have to do is to remove the Headers part from your Flow action, everything else looks OK. All you need is the POST method to the `_api/web/sitegroups/removebyid([id])`

Note the headers accepts JSON string, but you're providing it as a JS object. Removing it altogether will make it work.

As long as you're getting Status code 200, it means your flow ran successfully and it actually deleted your group.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've removed everything from the headers but after running the flow, the group still remains.

Comment: Can you try to create it as an instant flow (flow button for mobile), and test with the same logic? Just to make sure it's not something related to the existing flow instance or a permission thing.

Comment: I've just double checked that the user account is a site owner and created a new flow with the same result. New flow: [link](https://i.imgur.com/tIWEdan.png)